# Visual Studio Code : The 'C#' extension is recommended for this file type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, installation

So I recently installed visual studio code and added the C# available extensions. I also installed the Unity Debugger but it won't work because "it depends on an unknown 'ms-vscode.csharp' extension", I tried searching for this 'ms-vscode.csharp'in the extensions bar but found nothing. whenever i open a C# file from Unity or from any folder it recommends me to install that uknown C# extensions. what can i do please? here is a picture of the message:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To manually install the correct c# extension, do the following:

- Uninstall existing vscode C# plugin
- Close vscode
- Download the vsix [1.21.12 from here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.21.12)
- Open a command line in the folder where the vsix is.
- Type: `code --install-extension .\csharp-1.21.12.vsix`

You should see:

```
Installing extensions...
Extension 'csharp-1.21.12.vsix' was successfully installed.
```

Open VSCode and in the C# output window, you will see:

```
Installing C# dependencies...
Platform: win32, x86_64

Downloading package 'OmniSharp for Windows (.NET 4.6 / x64)' (32544 KB).................... Done!
Validating download...
Integrity Check succeeded.
Installing package 'OmniSharp for Windows (.NET 4.6 / x64)'
```

Errors should now have gone away.

Comment: the same solution also working for me using macOS catalina

Answer (score 4):

That was a mistake by Microsoft. I just spent hours to solve the problem and noticed that actually the name of the plugin was recently changed, leading to the error. We can fix it by manually downloading a previous version of the plugin.
Link:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp&ssr=false#review-details

Answer (score 0):

I don't do Unity development, but this may help: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

Keep in mind that VSCode is only going to be an editor for your project files.

(Can't comment, apologies for the brief answer)

Comment: thank you, but i just to install a previous version for the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I delete `[.vscode\extensions]`, swith to `1.21.1/February 2018` and then update to `1.42.1`. It finally works fine! 
Maybe System setup doesn't have the problem. It only occurs on User setup.

Answer (score 0):

That error happens because microsoft changed marketplace publisher from ms-vscode to ms-dotnettools. Mentioned [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3620) on github. You can just install the version v1.21.18 and that should solve it.

[image: VsCode version selection]